# Is it possible to configure Jenkins to NOT run a pipeline on branch discovery?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi-branch pipeline that has been configured to use branch auto-discovery. However I don't want Jenkins to automatically start a pipeline job when it discovers a new branch. I instead want the pipeline job to be started by another means (e.g. using a timer or via a REST API call).

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to get it straight: You want to prevent execution of the pipeline on (first) discovery? Any later execution should work "normally"?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, add the `Suppress automatic SCM triggering` property in the branch sources of your multibranch project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is perfect.

Comment: @Learner, did that do what you wanted? I believe that setting suppresses not only triggering the job on creation (branch discovery), but also suppresses triggering from scm events, like commits. I suppose since your last comment seems satisfied, probably so, but I just wanted to comment on this since it's not clear from this discussion the entire scope of what "Suppress automatic SCM triggering" does.

Answer (score -1):

You might revert to explicitly naming the branches you want to include
with auto-discovery using `Filter by name (with wildcards)`.

The documentation states: `Space-separated list of name patterns to consider. You may use * as a wildcard; for example: master release*`

So, adding any new branch to the list of included branches will ensure any changes after such addition will trigger processing as usual.

Any new branch will not be processed until it is explicitly included with the list.